# TypeError when adding variable

Tags: python, typeerror

I took working example code and tried to add another variable `self.species = martian` under the init method. Seems you cannot do this which doesn't make sense to me.

```
# A Sample class with init method 
class Person: 
    
    # init method or constructor 
    def __init__(self, name, species): 
        self.name = name 
        self.species = martian
    
    # Sample Method 
    def say_hi(self, name, species): 
        print('Hello, my name is', self.name)
        print('I am', self.species) 
    
p = Person('Martin')
p.say_hi()
```

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'species'
```

Comment: Well you have two problems: 1. yes, you don't pass that second argument; and 2. you don't use it in the method anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how your code should look like.

```
# A Sample class with init method 
class Person: 
    
    # init method or constructor 
    def __init__(self, name, species): 
        self.name = name 
        self.species = species
    
    # Sample Method 
    def say_hi(self): 
        print('Hello, my name is', self.name)
        print('I am', self.species) 
    
p = Person('Martin', 'martian')
p.say_hi()
```

I suggest you watch some other beginner's video lectures on 'init' method and 'Object oriented programming in python' before writing these type of codes otherwise it would be very hard to understand beyond this point

Answer (score 2):

When creating the person `p` you need to pass the *species* parameter.  As well, you are not using that argument in your function.

Calling could look like this:

```
p = Person("Martin", "martian")
```

Then within the constructor you reference the argument like this:

```
self.species = species
```